# why is it faster to resize a pointer to a vector* (in an array of vector*) than a vector (in an array of vector)?

Tags: c++, stdvector

resizing a vector might be slow ?
Desparating for solutions to improve my software speed, I tried to resize vectors in array of vector, and vector* in an array of vector*
The second seems faster. Even if I can feel the reason, I don't have a clear pure rational explanation (I don't want to use a reserve for vectors in the array as real ones are huge). Is there ?

Here is my test program (results might be different on another Lenovo ThinkCenter i5 with debian 8 : another task I don't want to stop is running) :

```
int main (int argc, char* argv []) {
  const int n = 10;
  const int s2 (10000);
  {
    std::vector<int> tab [n];
    clock_t begt, endt;
    begt = clock ();
    {
      std::vector<int>* pv ((std::vector<int>*) tab);
      for (int i (0); i < n; ++i, ++pv) {
        pv->resize (s2);
      }
    }
    endt = clock ();
    std::cout << "vector resize duration == " << (unsigned int) (endt - begt) <<  " ticks" << std::endl;
  }

  {
    std::vector<int> *tab [n];
    for (int i (0); i != n; ++i) {
      tab [i] = new std::vector<int> ();
    }
    clock_t begt, endt;
    begt = clock ();
    {
      std::vector<int>** pv ((std::vector<int>**) tab);
      for (int i (0); i < n; ++i, ++pv) {
        (*pv)->resize (s2);
      }
    }
    for (int i (0); i != n; ++i) {
      delete tab [i];
    }
    endt = clock ();
    std::cout << "*vector resize duration== " << (unsigned int) (endt - begt) <<  " ticks" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

and typical results :

```
vector resize duration == 114 ticks
*vector resize duration== 78 ticks
```

Comment: If you swap the snippets around, does that make a difference?

Comment: You cannot draw conclusions from single measurement. There's too many things at play that can affect it. Measure time of running each version 10000 times in a loop, divide that time by 10000 and you may have something to work with.

Comment: That's a trivial number of ticks. You can't measure performance like this!

Comment: Also, cache locality, _maybe_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got curious about the claimed observations, and was able to reproduce them myself. Then I swapped the two alternative implementations, and now the tables were turned. The `std::vector<int> *tab [n]` version, which now executes first, was now remarkably slower than the other one, which now executes second.

The explanation is very simple. The C++ library reuses allocated memory. When you use memory, either directly yourself, via `new`, or indirectly, by allocating memory for values in containers, and then later release it, the C++ library does not release the freed memory back to the operating system, but instead reuses it the next time it needs more memory, without having to ask your operating system for more. There is no law that says that this is what the C++ library must do, but this is a typical behavior of modern C++ implementations.

So, what this is, is very simple. Your first benchmark includes time required to allocate a bunch of memory from the operating system. The C++ needed memory for those vectors, the first time, and that took the additional time. Your second benchmark section of code did not have to do that, because that memory was already allocated, and then freed, by the first benchmark; so the second benchmark simply resulted in your C++ library reusing the memory it already had, but was unused (this was obvious by looking at the syscall trace).

Typical results from simply repeating the first benchmark a second time:

```
vector resize duration == 191 ticks
vector resize duration == 48 ticks
*vector resize duration== 63 ticks
```

Comment: I also swapped the tests and got the same results. The explanation was not that simple. Is it possible to parameter that reserve of standard library ?

Comment: It's very simple in the sense that this is a very straightforward, common way of managing memory, as anyone will learn in a class that focuses on operating system design and implementation. It's not exactly clear what you're asking, but in general you do not have any kind of low-level control over the memory allocation behavior of the C++ library, and any such controls, if they exist at all, are obviously not in scope of the C++ standard, and would be very much operating system-specific. You will need to consult the technical documentation of your OS or C++ library to determine if any exist.